# Publishing a project to Visual Studio 2012 Error Message : "Meta data file "SampleFileName.dll" could not be found."

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2012, metadata, publishing

Need help about Publishing a project to Visual Studio 2012

Error Message : "Metadata file "SampleFileName.dll" could not be found."

Troubleshoot
1. Clean rebuild
2. Close VS reopen VS
3. Config. Properties/ Config Manager: check or uncheck then check build
3. Delete .suo (I dont have a .suo file)
4. Restart the Computer

PS. 
I upgraded the project from VS2010 to VS2012 due to the need for some of the features of VS2012.

Comment: did you click APPLY after you UNCHECK it?

Comment: hi @Mark thanks for your response, yes i click the Apply

Comment: -- Solve i added the missing file to bin/release folder

Comment: Al lot of people are using VS2017 now. Have also a look at the framework version that the old project uses.